# Why is float.IsFinite “not defined” in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I use [`float.IsFinite(float f)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.single.isfinite?view=net-5.0#System_Single_IsFinite_System_Single_) in a C# shell, I have no problems. However, when I use it in the context of Unity, I get an error alleging that it is not defined:

[image: error CS0117: 'float' does not contain a definition for 'IsFinite']

Here is the relevent code:

```cs
public static bool IsFinite(Unit u) => float.IsFinite(u.blocks);
```

`Unit` is a struct in which I wrote the above line.

My question is: why does this error appear and how can I fix it?

Comment: because Unity does not (yet) support .NET 5

Comment: In fairness, `float.IsFinite` has been around since .NET Core 2.1 / .NET Standard 2.1. It's just that Unity supports .NET Standard 2.0.

Comment: Just use `!float.IsInfinity(u.blocks);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`float.IsFinite` exists in .NET 5, .NET Standard 2.1 and .NET Core 2.1. However Unity supports neither of those frameworks, just .NET Standard 2.0. This is why you cannot use the function here.

However it´s easy to create a workaround for the lack of that function:

```
public static bool IsFinite(Unit u) => !float.IsInfinity(u.blocks)
```

There´s an angoing [discussion at Unitity support forum about .NET 5](https://forum.unity.com/threads/net-5-support.839890/)